# Force open Python console when calling external Python code

Tags: python, labview

I have built some useful Python functions inside a `.py` file. I use this function through LabView calling it by a Python node and pass arguments to it (images as array). The calling to Python functions is transparent and no console is opened at runtime. Now I need to debug the Python code so I need the Python console to open and wait for user interaction in a step by step mode.

Labview version is 2018 and Python is 3.7. I have made some tries using the subprocess module but I can't run the functions defined in my Python script.

```py
def test():
    print("provaprova")
    return 0;

def debug_Command():
    subprocess.call("test", shell=True)
    return 0;
```

Comment: you can call pythonw in Windows, to open console, I suppose.

Comment: What is it that needs debugging? Are you happy that LabVIEW is calling the Python function and passing the arguments in OK, or is that where the problem is?

Comment: The problem is to pass the arguments. Like i said that was images, in labview imaq format, so i need to convert it to array (RGB, 3 array) and i don't know how to pass it if not programmatically. The problem is in the python code.

Comment: Well, it sounds as if your real question is *'how do I pass IMAQ images from LabVIEW into a Python script?'*. What about calling a temporary stub script that just saves the data from LabVIEW to a file using `pickle.dump`? Then you can `load` it in an interactive Python session and try out different ways of reading it.

Comment: This is a good idea! I will make a try.

Comment: You could try using TestScript: https://www.winemantech.com/testscript-download.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can run the python with your script and interactive mode:

The content of script:

```
$ cat test.py 
def test():
    print('Hello world')
```

And you can load the script and enter in interactive mode with `-i` :

```
$ python3 -i test.py
>>> test()
Hello world
>>>
```